# Spring Boot 2 + Oauth2: How to have separate logins for regular users and admins?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

So, I am using Spring Boot and Security for a while now. So far I only had one "kind" of user which were simply given roles `USER_ROLE` or `ADMIN_ROLE` in order to secure my REST endpoints.

However, I am now at a point where I realize: I only have *one* login. That is the default `/oauth/token` endpoint which, eventually, loads a user from my database and adds the authorities accordingly:

```java
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    username = username.trim();

    AppUserEntity appUserEntity = this.appUserRepository.findByEmail(username)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found."));

    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();

    Collection<AppUserRoleEntity> roles = appUserEntity.getRoles();

    for (AppUserRoleEntity appUserRoleEntity : roles) {
        RoleEntity roleEntity = appUserRoleEntity.getRole();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(roleEntity.getRoleType().toString()));
    }

    return new AppUserDetails(
            appUserEntity.getId(),
            appUserEntity.getEmail(),
            appUserEntity.getPassword(),
            authorities,
            appUserEntity.getActivated()
    );
}
```

The problem with this is, that there is no distinction between users. I do not know here which login (on my website) the user was using. A login will always work, even if a normal user uses the admin-login mask.

What I seek is a way to have different registration and login endpoints for admin and regular users. How would I do that?

I have seen [this tutorial](http://learningprogramming.net/java/spring-mvc/multiple-login-page-in-security-spring-mvc-framework-and-spring-data-jpa-part-2/) and also [this one](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-two-login-pages) but they do not use OAuth2.

What are my options here and/or what is the Spring Boot way to do this?

Comment: "The problem with this is, that there is no distinction between users". I think that is a wrong judgement. There is a distinction between users. Users with ADMIN_ROLE and  USER_ROLE are different. Purpose of assigning roles to users is to differentiate them. They all use the same login endpoint to authenticate but you can decide which role is going to have access to which endpoint, with configuration options available in spring-security.

Comment: @Johna Yes, but if e.g. a regular user enters her credentials into the admin-login form, I have no information about this fact if I use the `oauth/token` endpoint. At this point I cannot tell where the user tries to log in. All I know is whether this is an admin or not. But if the credentials are valid, she will be logged in. If I had, however, an `admin/oauth/token` and a `user/oauth/token` endpoint, the client would be able to use one of those. If a user then logs in over `admin/oauth/token`, she would receive an appropriate error.

Comment: @Johna I don't know if this is "*the*" way to do this but I don't know what else my options are here.

Comment: Please check the posted answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication and Authorization are two things. With OAuth, you are doing only the authentication part. Meaning, it checks whether the user has a valid username and a password. It is the application's responsibility to allow or deny access to certain areas of the application based on the grant/role assigned to the authenticated user.

You authenticate users with `oauth/token` endpoint and pass the token to the application with every request. Then in application's security configurations, you restrict **admin** area to only users who are in ADMIN_ROLE.

Please check the following section of a sample spring security configuration.

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()               //User must have a valid token                          
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN"); //User must be of ADMIN_ROLE
}
```

So, any user having a valid username and a password cannot access (login is a bit vague word) admin area of your application.

In the above configuration, if a non-admin user try to access `/admin/employee` after authenticating through `oauth/token`, it will throw 403 error. In other terms, that user is not allowed to login to that area of the application.

Comment: Well yes, and this is what I already have. But the problem with this is that *any* user can enter credentials on `/admin-login.html`. In this case, the login would work and the user would enter the administration app. Yes, requests to secured endpoints won't work, but I want the login to fail in the first place. Your answer resembles my current implementation.